# Returning NAN values when merging geodataframe with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, geopandas

I read in the data as following

```
polygons = polygons.geojson
polygons = gpd.read_file(polygons)

income = income.csv
provi_income = pd.read_csv(income)
```

```
income

    Primary_IncomeNet    identificatie
1               14734    PV20      
2               16502    PV21      
3               12917    PV22      
4               31189    PV23      
5               12060    PV24      
6               59168    PV25      
7               45021    PV26      
8               94199    PV27      
9              111357    PV28      
10              10405    PV29      
11              76537    PV30      
12              29362    PV31
```

```
polygons

  identificatie                                           geometry
0           PV20  MULTIPOLYGON (((265275.541 549247.459, 265285....
1           PV22  MULTIPOLYGON (((231437.815 516445.643, 231430....
2           PV26  MULTIPOLYGON (((131894.470 429932.357, 131917....
3           PV24  MULTIPOLYGON (((157694.139 473920.680, 159406....
4           PV23  MULTIPOLYGON (((248291.900 459808.449, 248302....
5           PV27  MULTIPOLYGON (((131700.944 464257.265, 131702....
6           PV25  MULTIPOLYGON (((181361.527 418255.386, 181384....
7           PV28  MULTIPOLYGON (((88397.000 413853.999, 89142.01...
8           PV21  MULTIPOLYGON (((189491.268 535832.617, 189494....
9           PV30  MULTIPOLYGON (((167891.450 359190.720, 168085....
10          PV31  MULTIPOLYGON (((199549.696 308385.049, 199558....
11          PV29  MULTIPOLYGON (((50235.786 357928.267, 50243.18...
```

And then merge based on common id. This merges the two data frames but the Primary_IncomeNet column shows NaN. Why does the  Primary_IncomeNet column not merge properly and how do perform the merge correctly?

```
merge = polygons.merge(income, on="identificatie", how= 'left')
```

```
 identificatie                                           geometry   Primary_IncomeNet
0           PV20  MULTIPOLYGON (((265275.541 549247.459, 265285....  NaN
1           PV22  MULTIPOLYGON (((231437.815 516445.643, 231430....  NaN
2           PV26  MULTIPOLYGON (((131894.470 429932.357, 131917....  NaN
3           PV24  MULTIPOLYGON (((157694.139 473920.680, 159406....  NaN
4           PV23  MULTIPOLYGON (((248291.900 459808.449, 248302....  NaN
5           PV27  MULTIPOLYGON (((131700.944 464257.265, 131702....  NaN
6           PV25  MULTIPOLYGON (((181361.527 418255.386, 181384....  NaN
7           PV28  MULTIPOLYGON (((88397.000 413853.999, 89142.01...  NaN
8           PV21  MULTIPOLYGON (((189491.268 535832.617, 189494....  NaN
9           PV30  MULTIPOLYGON (((167891.450 359190.720, 168085....  NaN
10          PV31  MULTIPOLYGON (((199549.696 308385.049, 199558....  NaN
11          PV29  MULTIPOLYGON (((50235.786 357928.267, 50243.18...  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the alignment of the column (`identificatie`) of the dataframe `income`, I suspect that she holds trailing whitespaces since their values are aligned to the left. So, try to [`strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) them before the merge.

```
income["identificatie"] = income["identificatie"].str.strip()
​
merge = polygons.merge(income, on="identificatie", how= "left")
```

​
Output:

```
print(merge)

   identificatie                                           geometry  Primary_IncomeNet
0           PV20  MULTIPOLYGON (((265275.541 549247.459, 265285....              14734
1           PV22  MULTIPOLYGON (((231437.815 516445.643, 231430....              12917
2           PV26  MULTIPOLYGON (((131894.470 429932.357, 131917....              45021
3           PV24  MULTIPOLYGON (((157694.139 473920.680, 159406....              12060
4           PV23  MULTIPOLYGON (((248291.900 459808.449, 248302....              31189
5           PV27  MULTIPOLYGON (((131700.944 464257.265, 131702....              94199
6           PV25  MULTIPOLYGON (((181361.527 418255.386, 181384....              59168
7           PV28  MULTIPOLYGON (((88397.000 413853.999, 89142.01...             111357
8           PV21  MULTIPOLYGON (((189491.268 535832.617, 189494....              16502
9           PV30  MULTIPOLYGON (((167891.450 359190.720, 168085....              76537
10          PV31  MULTIPOLYGON (((199549.696 308385.049, 199558....              29362
11          PV29  MULTIPOLYGON (((50235.786 357928.267, 50243.18...              10405
```